# Firebase Web data ordering in container

Tags: javascript, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working on a Firebase project and I'm stuck on data ordering.
Here's my javascript code:

```
function displayContent() {
  if (firstKey != null) {
    var i = 0;
    ref.orderByKey().endAt(firstKey).limitToLast(5).on("child_added", function(childSnapshot) {
      var childType;
      if (i == 0) {
        firstKey = null;
        childType = "lastChild";
      } else {
        childType = "firstChild";
      }
      i++;
      if (i < 5) {
        var containerElement = document.getElementsByClassName('post-container')[0];
        if (childSnapshot.val().image != null) {
          containerElement.insertBefore(
            createPostElementImg(
              childSnapshot.key, 
              childSnapshot.val().title, 
              childSnapshot.val().desc, 
              childSnapshot.val().image),
            containerElement.childType);
          if (firstKey == null) {
            firstKey = childSnapshot.key;
            console.log(firstKey);
          }
        } else {
          containerElement.insertBefore(
            createPostElement(
              childSnapshot.key, 
              childSnapshot.val().title, 
              childSnapshot.val().desc),
            containerElement.childType);
          if (firstKey == null) {
            firstKey = childSnapshot.key;
            console.log(firstKey);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(5).on("child_added", function(childSnapshot) {
      var containerElement = document.getElementsByClassName('post-container')[0];
      if (childSnapshot.val().image != null) {
        containerElement.insertBefore(
          createPostElementImg(
            childSnapshot.key, 
            childSnapshot.val().title, 
            childSnapshot.val().desc, 
            childSnapshot.val().image),
          containerElement.firstChild);
        if (firstKey == null) {
          firstKey = childSnapshot.key;
          console.log(firstKey);
        }
      } else {
        containerElement.insertBefore(
          createPostElement(
            childSnapshot.key, 
            childSnapshot.val().title, 
            childSnapshot.val().desc),
          containerElement.firstChild);
        if (firstKey == null) {
          firstKey = childSnapshot.key;
          console.log(firstKey);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The first call, when the firstKey is equal to null is ordered properly, but the data loaded onScroll (when the firstKey is not null) is displayed in the wrong order. Is there any way to sort that data?
Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I have this piece of code for the detection of the page being scrolled to the bottom:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var l_post = 0;
var n_post = 0;
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('Blog');
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
n_post = snapshot.numChildren();
console.log(n_post);
});
jQuery(
function($)
{
  $(".content").bind('scroll', function()
                            {
                              if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight()==$(this)[0].scrollHeight)
                              {
                                if(l_post < n_post) {
                                  displayContent();
                                  l_post = l_post + 5;
                                  console.log(l_post);
                                }
                              }
                            })
}
);
});
```

Comment: Why do you exactly mean by 'onScroll'?

Comment: I've edited the code and added the listener I use for the detection of the page beign scrolled to the bottom. Thanks!